# How to arrange the functions in the order of growth rate? So that f(n) is O(g(n))

Tags: performance, big-o, complexity-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have the below functions that needs to be ordered in their growth rate. But how can we show that the function g(n) immediately follows function f(n) in the list, then it should be the case that f(n) is O(g(n))?

[image: functions]

I tried by key-in some values for n (such as 10, 1000, 5000) and it is coming as 5 < 4 < 2 < 1 < 3, from 1000.

How can I prove this order asymptotically?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a mathematics question, not a computer programming question. (Use the definition of O(n): Calculate the limit f(n)/g(n).)

Comment: Use the definition of O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the answer below, posting in an image due to functions and powers.

[image: Answer]

Answer (score 0):

Any positive polynomial function grows faster than any poly-logarithmic function, that is, **lg^b(n) = o(n^a) for any a > 0** (note the small o)

This implies **f2 >> f4**.

Everything else (is an exponential) grows faster than f2.

Compare **f1 = 10^n** and **f3 = n^n**
Take log on both sides to compare **nlog10** to **nlogn**. Clearly, **f3 >> f1** (log10 is a constant).

Compare **f3 = n^n** and **f5 = 2^(log^1/2(n))**
Take on log both sides to compare **nlogn** to **(log^1/2(n))log2**. **f3 >> f5** (square both sides, or use the fact that: any positive polynomial function grows faster than any poly-logarithmic function)

All that is left is to compare **f5 = 2^(log^1/2(n))** and **f1 = 10^n**.
Take log on both sides to compare **(log^1/2(n))log2** to **nlog10**. **f1 >> f5**.

Using all of these facts it can be concluded that, **f4 << f2 << f5 << f1 << f3**. Alternatively, as others pointed out, you could compare them by computing the limits.